# Firebase Google authentication works in Chrome but not in Firefox: 'Application not validated by Google' error

Tags: google-chrome, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-oauth

I am currently using Firebase for user authentication, notifications, and real-time database.
My problem concerns authentication via Google through Firebase.
The entire process works correctly on some browsers like Chrome, but on other browsers like Firefox, I receive a window indicating that the application has not been validated by Google.

Here is the screen in question:

[image]

It seems that the configuration is not correct on the Google side.
When I indicate that I want to access the site, I then have a second screen where I have to hide "Show and download your contacts":

[image]

Is this the missing information on the Google side?

For your information, here are all the functions I use on the JavaScript side:

```
import { sendPasswordResetEmail, updatePassword, sendEmailVerification , createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithRedirect , signInWithPopup, FacebookAuthProvider, GoogleAuthProvider, getAuth, setPersistence , browserLocalPersistence, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getDatabase, ref , set , onValue } from "firebase/database";
import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from "firebase/messaging";
```

On the Google side, at the OAuth consent screen, I have tried to select the levels of access I need. Here is my configuration:

[image]
[image]

My application has been validated, however, I still receive the error message that the application has not been validated by Google during the authentication attempt on Firefox.
Are there any missing accesses, or are there too many?
On Chrome, as I said, everything works fine.